# How do I know my actual damage done to monsters?

Tags: diablo-iii

Diablo III has been statisticized. I can see every conceivable stat in my inventory screen now including my (estimated) DPS. However, I want to see the damage I'm actually doing to monsters. Every once in a while I see some yellow numbers flash above monsters but they're way higher than my DPS, I expect they're probably crits. Can I see the damage done for non-crits too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an option to display damage numbers within the menu configuration options.

By default, it will only show critical damage, but it's easy to make it show all damage.

[image: Let me go see if I can pull up a screenshot of where to go.]
*This picture brought to you by Freehand Circles*

Comment: Not only did you beat me by 1 minute, but your freehand circles are cooler than mine! I'll admit defeat and delete my answer!

Comment: Damn, I hate the menu system in DIII, I swear I looked through them.

Comment: @authenticgeek You may have looked through them but did you read them? :OP